# Pivot Wider not spreading the values correctly, it is returning NAs

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm working with the monthly National Employment Report (NER) from ADP. The goal is to pivot wider so analysis can be done, but pivot wider is not working for me.

The raw data is at their main page (https://adpemploymentreport.com), or I have it at:

```
National_Employment_Report <-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/InfiniteCuriosity/forecasting_jobs/main/ADP_NER_history.csv")
```

The goal is to have each category as its own column.

I've tried this:

```
ADP_National_Employment_Report %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = category,
    values_from = c(NER))
```

But that returns the values in the categories as NAs. Same for quite a few variations, such as this:

```
ADP_National_Employment_Report %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = category,
    values_from = NER_SA,
    values_fn = sum
)
```

but almost all the values in all the categories are NAs, like this:

[image]

I've also converted the categories into factors, that made no difference at all, they were nearly all filled with NAs, as before.

Comment: Without downloading your data, you probably want to use `values_fn = \(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)` .

Comment: quick question: the data contains both census division aggregations as well as establishment size aggregations (number of employees). It doesn't have ones for number of employees for different census areas. Are you wanting all of these to be in the same dataframe? Because it ends up with some columns having all NAs in (for example) the 1-19 employees column

Comment: @RitchieSacramento the issue is that there's two value columns, NER_SA and NER

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues with the data:
The first is that it appears that your dataframe has four distinct types of data in it:

1. Census division data
2. Establishment size data
3. Industry data
4. National data

The second is that there are two different columns which could reasonably be used as values in a pivot_wider() call, `NER` and `NER_SA`

The reason for all of the NAs is that you're keeping in the `NER` column when pivoting wider, even though you're creating many columns, it's not creating one row per date because the `NER` makes the rows non-identical.

Once this is done, however, we run into the second issue - the categories for each of the data types listed above use different columns, so if we just remove the `NER` column and pivot_wider, we will get a dataframe with values in all of the census division columns, but it will have all of the other three columns, with NAs in all those columns, which isn't ideal.

The best way is to split the dataframe based on the agg_RIS column, and remove `NER`, and pivot_wider for each of the child dataframes:

```
library(tidyverse)

National_Employment_Report |> 
  group_split(agg_RIS) |>
  map(\(df) df |> 
              select(-NER) |>
              pivot_wider(names_from= category, values_from = NER_SA))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 871 × 12
   timestep agg_RIS          date      `East North Central` `East South Central`
   <chr>    <chr>            <chr>                    <dbl>                <dbl>
 1 M        Census Divisions 2010-01-…             16203000              5682000
 2 M        Census Divisions 2010-02-…             16169000              5667000
 3 M        Census Divisions 2010-03-…             16237000              5644000
 4 M        Census Divisions 2010-04-…             16279000              5650000
 5 M        Census Divisions 2010-05-…             16315000              5534000
 6 M        Census Divisions 2010-06-…             16339000              5542000
 7 M        Census Divisions 2010-07-…             16370000              5596000
 8 M        Census Divisions 2010-08-…             16394000              5576000
 9 M        Census Divisions 2010-09-…             16439000              5557000
10 M        Census Divisions 2010-10-…             16472000              5562000
# ℹ 861 more rows
# ℹ 7 more variables: `Mid-Atlantic` <dbl>, Mountain <dbl>,
#   `New England` <dbl>, Pacific <dbl>, `South Atlantic` <dbl>,
#   `West North Central` <dbl>, `West South Central` <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 871 × 8
   timestep agg_RIS date  `1-19 employees` `20-49 employees` `250-499 employees`
   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>            <dbl>             <dbl>               <dbl>
 1 M        Establ… 2010…         29192000          18157000             9387000
 2 M        Establ… 2010…         29149000          18125000             9420000
 3 M        Establ… 2010…         29018000          18121000             9424000
 4 M        Establ… 2010…         29019000          18144000             9464000
 5 M        Establ… 2010…         28996000          18192000             9486000
 6 M        Establ… 2010…         28946000          18194000             9508000
 7 M        Establ… 2010…         28957000          18225000             9545000
 8 M        Establ… 2010…         28994000          18235000             9569000
 9 M        Establ… 2010…         28970000          18220000             9566000
10 M        Establ… 2010…         28915000          18227000             9595000
# ℹ 861 more rows
# ℹ 2 more variables: `50-249 employees` <dbl>, `500+ employees` <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

[[3]]
# A tibble: 871 × 13
   timestep agg_RIS  date       Construction `Education and health services`
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>             <dbl>                           <dbl>
 1 M        Industry 2010-01-01      5342000                        18247000
 2 M        Industry 2010-02-01      5340000                        18248000
 3 M        Industry 2010-03-01      5309000                        18304000
 4 M        Industry 2010-04-01      5281000                        18326000
 5 M        Industry 2010-05-01      5268000                        18407000
 6 M        Industry 2010-06-01      5260000                        18439000
 7 M        Industry 2010-07-01      5286000                        18488000
 8 M        Industry 2010-08-01      5280000                        18510000
 9 M        Industry 2010-09-01      5238000                        18503000
10 M        Industry 2010-10-01      5217000                        18556000
# ℹ 861 more rows
# ℹ 8 more variables: `Financial activities` <dbl>, Information <dbl>,
#   `Leisure and hospitality` <dbl>, Manufacturing <dbl>,
#   `Natural resources and mining` <dbl>, `Other services` <dbl>,
#   `Professional and business services` <dbl>,
#   `Trade, transportation, and utilities` <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

[[4]]
# A tibble: 871 × 4
   timestep agg_RIS  date            U.S.
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>
 1 M        National 2010-01-01 104041000
 2 M        National 2010-02-01 103998000
 3 M        National 2010-03-01 104000000
 4 M        National 2010-04-01 104277000
 5 M        National 2010-05-01 104364000
 6 M        National 2010-06-01 104420000
 7 M        National 2010-07-01 104647000
 8 M        National 2010-08-01 104723000
 9 M        National 2010-09-01 104847000
10 M        National 2010-10-01 104878000
# ℹ 861 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```